# outlook EntryId syntax

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am writing a tool to backup my mails. In order to understand if I have already backed up a mail I use the entryID. 
The Entry ID is however very very long and so I have problems in serializing my datastructure with JSON, using the entryID as index in a hash. 
Furthermore I noticed that the first part of the entryID remains identic throughout all my mails. Therefore my suspect, that the first part identifies the Outlook Server, and the last part the e-mails themselves. Therefore there should no need to use the whole entryID to identify a single mail in my account.
Anybody knows the syntax of this entryID, I did not find nothing on the Microsoft Site, maybe I did the wrong query.
Thx a lot

Example of EntryID:
          00000000AC032ADC2BFB3545BD2CEE24F67EAFF507000C7E507D761D09469E2B3AC3FA5E65770034EA28BA320000FD962E1BCA05E74595C077ACB6D7D7D30001C72579700000
quite long, isnt´t it ?

Comment: The Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-entryid-property-outlook

Answer (score 0):

All entry ids must be treated as black boxes. The first 4 bytes (8 hex characters) are the flags (0s for the long term entry id). Next 16 bytes (32 hex characters) are the provider UID registered with the M